# d3 tickvalues in an if statement

Tags: d3.js

this is my x-axis generating code right now:

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickFormat(function (d, i) {

        if (interval_size === "15" || interval_size === "30") {
            return testStringArray[i];
        }
        else {
            return dateArray[i];
        }

    })
.tickValues(x.domain().filter(function (d, i) { return !(i % 2); }));
```

I wanted to know if it is possible to put the .tickValues in an if statement and execute it only if a certain condition arises?

I have tried putting an if in the anonymous function.  That doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to use `.tickValues` if some condition is met?

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
  .tickFormat(function (d, i) {
      if (interval_size === "15" || interval_size === "30") {
        return testStringArray[i];
      } else {
        return dateArray[i];
      }
  });

if (someCondition){
  xAxis.tickValues(x.domain().filter(function (d, i) { return !(i % 2); }));
}
```